# Only last radio button triggers $viewChangeListener

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have a set of radio buttons and a text input in a form. The text input has some validation applied that depends on the selected radio button.

**HTML:**

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate>
    <div class="radio">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="myValue" name="radioGroup" value="1">1</input>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="myValue" name="radioGroup" value="2">2</input>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="myValue" name="radioGroup" value="3">3</input>
    </div>
    <div class="otherFormComponent">
        <input type="text" ng-model="myTextValue" name="textValue" special-validator></input>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
app.directive('specialValidator', function(){
    return{
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl){
            ctrl.$validators.specialValidator = function(modelValue, viewValue){
                //Do some validation
            };

            //Force validation when a radio button changes
            scope.myForm.radioGroup.$viewChangeListeners.push(function(){
                scope.myForm.textValue.$validate();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Unfortunately, the `scope.myForm.textValue.$validate()` code is only triggered whenever the *last* radio button (3) is selected. Selecting other radio buttons does not trigger the method added to `scope.myForm.radioGroup.$viewChangeListeners`.

How can one set up radio buttons so that a change in any radio button will trigger the `viewChangeListeners`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've concluded that this must be a bug in angular. Here's my workaround using `scope.$watch`

**HTML**

(Added the radio-group-model attribute to the text input, which must the same as the ng-model value of the radio button group that validation depends upon.)

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate>
    <div class="radio">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="myValue" name="radioGroup" value="1">1</input>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="myValue" name="radioGroup" value="2">2</input>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="myValue" name="radioGroup" value="3">3</input>
    </div>
    <div class="otherFormComponent">
        <input type="text" ng-model="myTextValue" name="textValue" special-validator
            radio-group-model="myValue"></input>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JS:**

(Using `scope.$watch` instead of adding a function to the radioGroup's `viewChangeListeners`.)

```
app.directive('specialValidator', function(){
    return{
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl){
            ctrl.$validators.specialValidator = function(modelValue, viewValue){
                //Do some validation
            };

            //Force validation when a radio button changes
            scope.$watch(attrs.radioGroupModel, function(value){
                scope.myForm.textValue.$validate();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I reported this bug to angular: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15696

They advise to use different `name` attributes for the different inputs.